# Is there a keyboard shortcut for inserting a new line above the one the caret is on?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I can do `command-return` to create a new line *under* the current one, even if the caret is in the middle of a word, but I often find myself wishing there was a similar command for inserting a line above and moving the caret to it. Does that exist?

I know I can type out my new line and then move it, but it'd be nice to skip that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep: `⌘ (Command) + shift + enter` if you're on a Mac

Found [here](https://blog.bugsnag.com/atom-editor-cheat-sheet/)